# Lua HTTP Request TCP messages

Tags: http, lua

I am sending HTTP requests using socket.http to a Shelly 2.5 relay IOT device that contains a Mongoose/6.18 server running on an ESP8266, but am having problems.

HTTP requests to this device work as expected when initiated from postman or browser: the device's server responds as expected.

However if I send requests using Lua 5.3 socket.http module, the server does NOT respond. I've used tcpdump to see what's going on and from what I see, unlike browsers or postman which send the HTTP request in **one TCP message** containing both the HTTP startline and headers, Lua seems to send **two separate TCP messages**, first for the startline only, then a second for the headers. Mongoose responds with an ack when the startline is sent, then Lua sends the headers and Mongoose does not respond. Lua then tries 5 times to resend the headers before giving up.

I don't normally have problems using socket.http when sending HTTP requests to other servers.

I'm not sure if the 2-part HTTP message is what is causing the issue with this particular device, or if I'm perhaps misinterpreting the tcpdump output:

```
18:24:23.823886 IP 192.168.1.140.41894 > 192.168.1.136.http: Flags [P.], seq 1:151, ack 1, win 65392, length 150: HTTP: GET /settings/actions?index=0&name=out_on_url&enabled=true&urls[]=http://192.168.1.107:6667/b6cb7ffc-7919-41e6-ab80-6bed8b117753/relay/0/on HTTP/1.1
E.....@.@.6............Pj.n.....P..p....GET /settings/actions?index=0&name=out_on_url&enabled=true&urls[]=http://192.168.1.107:6667/b6cb7ffc-7919-41e6-ab80-6bed8b117753/relay/0/on HTTP/1.1

18:24:23.898872 IP 192.168.1.136.http > 192.168.1.140.41894: Flags [.], ack 151, win 2770, length 0
E..(.6@...v5.........P......j.o:P.
.......5...
18:24:23.898946 IP 192.168.1.140.41894 > 192.168.1.136.http: Flags [P.], seq 151:447, ack 1, win 65392, length 296: HTTP
E..P..@.@.5{...........Pj.o:....P..p....Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: 192.168.1.136
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: LuaSocket 3.0-rc1
TE: trailers
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


18:24:24.125746 IP 192.168.1.140.41894 > 192.168.1.136.http: Flags [P.], seq 151:447, ack 1, win 65392, length 296: HTTP
E..P..@.@.5z...........Pj.o:....P..p....Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: 192.168.1.136
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: LuaSocket 3.0-rc1
TE: trailers
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


18:24:24.575743 IP 192.168.1.140.41894 > 192.168.1.136.http: Flags [P.], seq 151:447, ack 1, win 65392, length 296: HTTP
E..P..@.@.5y...........Pj.o:....P..p....Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: 192.168.1.136
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: LuaSocket 3.0-rc1
TE: trailers
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


18:24:25.495791 IP 192.168.1.140.41894 > 192.168.1.136.http: Flags [P.], seq 151:447, ack 1, win 65392, length 296: HTTP
E..P..@.@.5x...........Pj.o:....P..p....Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: 192.168.1.136
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: LuaSocket 3.0-rc1
TE: trailers
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9


18:24:27.328180 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.136 tell 192.168.1.1, length 46
........`.'.................>.[p.....!.....
>.
18:24:27.335732 IP 192.168.1.140.41894 > 192.168.1.136.http: Flags [P.], seq 151:447, ack 1, win 65392, length 296: HTTP
E..P..@.@.5w...........Pj.o:....P..p....Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: 192.168.1.136
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: LuaSocket 3.0-rc1
TE: trailers
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: Could you show your Lua code?

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this - it turns out the device I was sending the message to was spontaneously restarting as soon as it read the first part of the message - thus its failure to receive the rest and respond.  Obviously a bug in their firmware, and unfortunately Shelly wasn't too interested in fixing it after several messages and data dumps sent to their tech support.